# How doesn't this page work with Collapse.js in Bootstrap 3.3.4?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap v.3.3.4. All of my resources are relatively linked and the html file is in the right location to access them.

I'm making a 'Learn More' button and have it show a collapsed unordered list either above it or below it when pressed.

**I can't get any button or link to toggle a collapsed element.**

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#moreInfo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">Learn More</button>
        <div class="collapse" id="moreInfo">
            <div class="well">
                <ul>
                    <li>list item 1</li>
                    <li>list item 2</li>
                    <li>list item 3</li>
                    <li>list item 4</li>
                    <li>list item 5</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks to Hyu Kim, I added the jquery library (v1.11.3) to the page but I'm not seeing any collapsing.

I'm opening this locally (it's not hosted anywhere), could that be part of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just forgot to link jquery library. :)

your html lines work just fine if you try at: http://www.bootply.com/new#

if that doesn't work, you can explicitly invoke collapse on initial load.

```
$('#moreInfo').collapse();
```

Comment: you can add this line before `</body>`
`<script type="text/javascript">$('#moreInfo').collapse();</script>`

Comment: if that doesn't work. please read this. your bootstrap.min is missing plugin that takes care of collapse

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse

Comment: According to http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#transitions the most current bootstrap.min.js (v3.4.4) should have it already... I'll double check this though, thank you!